# PyPDF2 unable to compress pdf

Tags: python, streamlit, pypdf

I want to show an embed pdf on streamlit app which has a limitation of <2MB pdf size to be displayed.

So I am trying to compress the pdf file which a user uploads via st.file_uploader on streamit app using PyPDF2 package. Here's the code I used:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter
from io import BytesIO

def compress_pdf(pdf_file, target_size):
  # Load PDF using PyPDF2
    pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf_file)

    # Compress PDF using PyPDF2
    output_pdf = BytesIO()
    pdf_writer = PdfWriter()
    for page in pdf_reader.pages:
        page.compress_content_streams()  # This is CPU intensive!
        pdf_writer.add_page(page)

    # Get the compressed PDF bytes
    pdf_writer.write(output_pdf)
    compressed_pdf_bytes = output_pdf.getvalue()
    print(len(compressed_pdf_bytes)) # Check output of compressed pdf

    return compressed_pdf_bytes
```

The above function takes in the file uploaded by the user on streamlit as below:

```
uploaded_file = st.sidebar.file_uploader("Upload a file", key= "uploaded_file")
print(st.session_state.uploaded_file)

if uploaded_file is not None:
    compressed_pdf_bytes= compress_pdf(uploaded_file, 2000000)
```

Even after doing all that, I see the file isn't compressed AT ALL.

This is the output in terminal as u see. The file uploaded (output of  and the length of compressed_pdf_bytes is almost same.

```
#Output of actual file uploaded.
UploadedFile(id=6, name='abc.pdf', type='application/pdf', size=4588407)

#output of compressed file in bytes
4472714
```

Comment: Please point to an example file to see, whether PyMuPDF can do a better job - fat chance for that! However, there do exist PDFs which already have been compressed to the most possible extent.

Comment: Please formulate a question. The statement "PyPDF2 unable to compress pdf" is obviously wrong as the new file is smaller than the original one.

Comment: See also: https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/file-size.html

Comment: @MartinThoma New file is almost same size as old one

Comment: @JorjMcKie Here's an example pdf which is 3.7 MB and it's not getting under 2 MB

https://www.nccn.org/patients/guidelines/content/PDF/lung-early-stage-patient.pdf

Comment: The example file is even 4.37 MB on download. Standard compression only reduces by 4%. No hope **ever** to get below 2 MB here! Images are the problem: if I delete them all, the resulting size is 874.730 bytes.

Comment: Just tested it: replacing images by their gray versions with PyMuPDF reduces the file size from 4.37 to 3.44 MB. So you must decide what to do. Maybe a combination of gray image conversion and splitting the PDF into parts?

Comment: don't actually need images. Just need text and anything that's inside tables.

Comment: There was a pdftotext package that used to work in converting all pdf content to text. 

Somehow that package no longer works. I think if I get something like that, I am ok as I don't really need images in the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try PyMuPDF: `python -m pip install pymupdf`.
Then do this

```py
import fitz  # pymupdf

def compress_pdf(pdf_file, target_size):
    # Load PDF using pymupdf
    doc = fitz.open(pdf_file)
    compressed_pdf_bytes = doc.tobytes(
        deflate=True,
        garbage=4,
    )
    print(len(compressed_pdf_bytes)) # Check output of compressed pdf
    return compressed_pdf_bytes
```

The above solution is lossless!
You can also try to build subset fonts - if your PDFs contain fonts that are not subsetted, the gain may be significant.

If your 2 MB limit is a hard one and you are ready to sacrifice things: PyMuPDF also offers to remove images.
With some more programming effort, you can also replace images by their gray-scale equivalents.

Here is a snippet to remove all images from a PDF:

```py
doc = fitz.open(pdf_file)
for page in doc:
    for xref in [item[0] for item in page.get_images()]:
        page.delete_image(xref)
doc.save("no-images.pdf", garbage=4, deflate=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `cpdf -squeeze in.pdf -o out.pdf` which is lossless compression.

Generally speaking, if your file has been created competently, there should be little space to squeeze. Especially if it is mostly images and fonts.

Answer (score 0):

It is not always possible to compress the file. At some point, it has its minimal form.

The [pypdf docs about file size](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/file-size.html) give some important hints. They especially point out that removing images can reduce the file size.

Comment: if I want to remove all images and only keep all text and yet pass it as pdf, how will that work?